# How to randomly classify my table for academic research

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has 12 million records and around 60,000 reports and it looks like this

```
RepID  Name   DS2
-----------------------------
1      Mike   
1      John
1      Lisa
1      Matt
2      John
2      Ali
2      Tom
2      Suzy
3      Dave
3      Mike
3      Nancy
....
60000  Rida
60000  Matt
60000  Hani
```

This table has to be classified randomly for academic research.

2,000 random Reps in each group Ex. (RepIDs : 62, 8203, 8473,18493,... will be in group 1)

Reps : 9387,33772, 64, 10493, ... in group 2

and so on till group 30

I can do this in a while loop but it is very slow

Is there a faster way?

End results should be like this

```
RepID  Name   DS2
-----------------------------
1      Mike   22
1      John   22
1      Lisa   22
1      Matt   22
2      John   19
2      Ali    19
2      Tom    19
2      Suzy   19
3      Dave   6
3      Mike   6
3      Nancy  6
....
60000  Rida   19
60000  Matt   19
60000  Hani   19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay to have group in ascending order of repid.

```
with cte as 
(
    select *
        , (dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY repid)-1) / 2000 + 1 AS GroupId
    from mytable
)
update cte set ds2 = groupId
```

To have random repid in group I have generated some random id for each group and saved it to a temp table. Then joined this table with original table to have random order.

```
create table #RANDOMREP
(  
repid int,  
randomrepid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   
)
 INSERT INTO #RANDOMREP
 select repid,newid() newRepId
    from MYTABLE  
    group by repid;
    
    
with cte as 
(
    select *
        , (dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY randomrepid)-1) / 2000 + 1 AS GroupId
    from mytable m inner join #RANDOMREP r on m.repid=r.repid
)
update cte set ds2 = groupId
```

Comment: maybe use newid() in `order by` to make it random

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMenoutis. But OP wants to randomize repId not rows. all the rows belong to any repid should be in one group.

Comment: This is not random, number are sequantial first 2000 are DS2 = 1

Comment: can a repid be part of more than one group?

Comment: @asmgx I have revised my answer

Answer (score 1):

We can do that using that Query where 30 is your page number & MySampleTable is your table name

```
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY (RoWNum % 30) ORDER BY RoWNum) MyRank, *
    From
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () over (order by NEWID()) RoWNum, *
     FROM MySampleTable) X
    ORDER BY 1
```

The [Order by NEWID()] in the inner query will randomize your records, then the DENSE_RANK will use that generated Row_Number to distribute it into groups of 30